# TermSymbol.isVal doesn't look correct

Tags: scala

I have following code to check whether `x` in class A is val or var

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
class A {
  val x = 10
}

val y: Symbol = typeOf[A].member(TermName("x"))
println(y.asTerm.isVal + "," + y.asTerm.isVar)
println()
```

The output is:

```
false,false
```

`x` is declared as val, I would ask why `y.asTerm.isVal` is evaluated as false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a hint if you do this:

```
typeOf[A].decls // List everything inside A
SynchronizedOps(constructor A, value x, value x)
```

There are two `value x`s, because `x` exists in two forms. Remember Scala's Uniform Access Principle: public `val`s are never truly public. Instead, they are a `private[this] val` combined with a generated getter `def`. One `value x` in the list is the `private[this] val x`, and the other is the `def x = x` (invalid Scala, but that's how it is). You can define the class with `-Xprint:typer` to see it.

`typeOf[A].member(TermName("x"))`, then, returns the public `def x` instead of returning the `private[this] val x`. You can do (from least to most specific) `y.asTerm.isMethod`/`.isAccessor`/`.isGetter` to verify this.

If you just need to get the setter for the field, you can call `y.asTerm.setter`, which will return `def x_=` if `x` is a `var`, and will return `NoSymbol` if there isn't a setter. If you need the field itself, you can call `y.asTerm.accessed.asTerm`, which is actually a `val`: `y.asTerm.accessed.asTerm.isVal`.